# Difference between ISODates in each document?

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo, timedelta

Is it possible to calculate the difference between two dates in a document **server-side**, and query on it? (Like SQL's [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms189794.aspx) function)

Assume I have a number of documents like this:

```
>>> db.collection.find()
[
    { "id" : ObjectId("1"), 
      "starttime" : ISODate("2011-12-01T05:01:00"), # 5:01 AM
      "endtime" : ISODate("2011-12-01T05:02:00")    # 5:02 AM 
    }, 

    { "id" : ObjectId("2"), 
      "starttime" : ISODate("2011-12-01T06:01:00"), # 6:01:00 AM
      "endtime" : ISODate("2011-12-01T06:01:30")    # 6:01:30 AM 
    }
]
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar to this?

Returning just time difference:

```
>>> db.collection.date_difference_seconds(endtime, starttime)
[60, 30]
```

or a query:

```
>>> db.collection.find("timediff(endtime-starttime) < 40 seconds")
[
    { "id" : ObjectId("2"), ...} # Just second document (30s diff)
]
```

I've read about [server-side JS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/server-side-javascript/) and `eval()`, but the docs say these are not recommended - are they the best option?

---

(I can obviously add the time difference in seconds as an additional field (`"time_diff": 30`), or calculate the differences in Python client-side, but I'd like to know if it's possible server-side)

Client-side calc:

```
>>> for doc in (collection.find(None, {'starttime': 1, 'endtime': 1 }))
        doc['endtime']-doc['startime']
0:01:00.000000
0:00:30.000000
```

Comment: I presume that to do this you must know the time difference you wish to query on? So why not just query by the different dates and calculate the difference client side?

Comment: @Sammaye I'm not sure I follow. I'm only interested in the difference between dates, not the dates themselves. Do you mean something like the snippet I've added to my question?

Comment: I don't think there's a special method to do it sever side, but it can be done in one statement client side. For example: map(lambda x: (x['endtime'] - x['starttime']).total_seconds(), db.collection.find())

Comment: Ok actually I understand what your trying to do: `db.collection.find("timediff(endtime-starttime) < 40 seconds")` I thought it was simpler but I didn't think enough about it. Hmmm, there is the possibility of using a `$where` here adding the time calc function to that, this would avoid eval but it will seriously reduce speed. I think that if you were to use the aggregation function to make a new computed field using the http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have the equivalent. So, if it's a frequent query, just precompute it as you suggested and store in an additional field. You could add an index and sort, etc. that way (if needed). Or possibly a MapReduce function, but the field would be simpler.

Comment: @Sammaye It looks like calculating time difference using aggregation data operators would be pretty complex, I think an extra field is the way to go. (I'm used the mantra of not repeating data from RDBs). Cheers guys - if someone summarises all this an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: Well really the separate field is your original answer so you should probably answer :) that after some talking you decided to go with the original idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Sammaye, I think the only way to do it is with the aggregate() function. For example, doing something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {timediff: {$subtract: ['$endtime' , '$starttime']}}}])
```

You're essentially defining a new run-time field, "timediff", which is calculated off of existing data. You should then be able to add a `$match` step to the pipeline to filter on the difference:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {timediff: {$subtract: ['$endtime' , '$starttime']}}}, {$match: {timediff: {$lte: 40}}}])
```

I haven't tried this specific example so there might be a few missing braces or brackets...but hopefully you get the idea. The aggregation framework is pretty powerful in terms of the data pipelines you can define.

Good luck!

Comment: Just a comment about it. $lte : 40 is not 40 seconds, at least the current mongodb version I'm using at this moment returns milliseconds. So it should be $lte : 40000 to get a 40 seconds difference